# Build phong shader from THREE.ShaderLib

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'm trying to build the phong shader from THREE.ShaderLib.
This is what I got:

```
var phongShader = THREE.ShaderLib.phong;
var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(phongShader.uniforms);

material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: uniforms,
  vertexShader: phongShader.vertexShader,
  fragmentShader: phongShader.fragmentShader
});
```

It doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jvf9k/2/
Similar SO question: [Three js - Cloning a shader and changing uniform values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091795/three-js-cloning-a-shader-and-changing-uniform-values)

Edit: Updated the fiddle with the help of Tapio answer. It now works!

Comment: Try `THREE.ShaderLib['phong'];`

Comment: @gaitat - That's just the same thing in different (longer and potentially less efficient) notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSFiddle is using `THREE.CanvasRenderer` which doesn't (and can't) support shader materials (but can support the built-in materials). Change that to `THREE.WebGLRenderer`. Also, it doesn't make sense to use phong material without lights as the result will be all black. Phong with wireframe doesn't sound very useful either.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! Off course! I can't believe I missed that. I updated the fiddle and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

add lights and fog:

```
var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: uniforms,
    vertexShader: phongShader.vertexShader,
    fragmentShader: phongShader.fragmentShader,
    lights:true,
    fog: true
});
```

Comment: This immediately fixed my issues with accepting `uniforms` - how does this work?